# Gratis PHP framework for AJAX (only)

Tags: gratis, php, framework

I have been coding PHP for a few decades now, but have never used a framework. Instead I have a home-brew collection of common functionality.

I am considering a PHP framework and wonder what is available. I welcome answers from personal experience.

I am interested in AJAX only, but won't reject anything that handles other stuff, just as long as I get good, stable AJAX (the only non-Ajax functionality that I can imagine using is user registration/change password/lost password, but I can get that elsewhere).

- I currently use PDO to connect to MySql and would like that to be supported.
- I would appreciate good exception handling & debugging possibilities.
- and security features
- I suppose that raw speed plays a part.
- as does documentation, examples, tutorials, forums

Anything other features? I am not really sure what to expect from a framework.

Comment: https://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/ is helpful. For instance, CakePhp allows one to say that a HP fiel can be accessed by AJAX only, not directly by URL in the browser (does Lavarel also offer this?).

Answer (score 1):

I use laravel for a few years now and I'm very happy with that framework. Documentation can be found on https://laravel.com

If you need only backend functionality for maybe an API there is also a smaller and lighter version available called lumen. Infos at https://lumen.laravel.com

There are also many other ones like http://www.slimframework.com or https://silex.symfony.com

In the end you have to compare a few for yourself to test which one fits your needs.

What to expect from laravel framework:

- very easy to use database handling (With model classes; called "[eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent)")
- build in error handling [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/errors#the-exception-handler)
- build in security features like [authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication), [encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/encryption), [email verification](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/verification)
- build in support for different file [storages](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem) (local, S3, ftp, ...)
- queue, jobs, tasks
- official packages for api [authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport), [payments](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/billing), ...
- and tons of other features

To get started with API development you would create a [route](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing) like

```
Route::get('version', function () {
    return ['version' => 'v0.0.1'];
});
```

and call it from javascript like

```
fetch('/version')
.then((response) => {
  return response.json();
})
.then((myJson) => {
  console.log('API version: ' + myJson.version);
});
```

Comment: Welcome aboard, and thank you for such a detailed first post !